Windows is deprecated in WidgetsBinding
window in this line of code WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio is deprecated.
Code:
var pixelRatio = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
var size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize / pixelRatio;


https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/BindingBase/window.html

this will work:
final view = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first;
final pixelRatio = view.devicePixelRatio;
final size = view.physicalSize / pixelRatio;

here
